# what is the logic behind Makefile patterns?

Tags: file, makefile, pattern-matching

I used to think that '%' in Makefiles was the equivalent to '*' in bash, therefore something like this would make sense:

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

However, it doesn't work when trying to retrieve files starting with something, which in bash can be done like `ls test*`, for example:

```
#retrieve all files starting with test
test%: %.c
    gcc $< -o $@
```

Can anyone explain how this could be done?

Comment: `FILES := $(wildcard test*)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work exactly like `*` in shell globbing, except that `%` must match at least one character while `*` can match zero characters.

If you have problems please be sure to use a real example, and show the command you typed and the output you got, and explain why that output is not what you wanted, else we can only guess.

First, you don't add a colon to the end of your pattern rule; since that's a syntax error I'll assume that your real makefile just has one colon:

```
test%: %.c
        ...
```

You haven't given us an actual example so we can't say for sure, but most likely the problem you are having is forgetting that the value of `%` must be identical in the target and prerequisite for the rule to match.

So if you have a pattern rule with `test% : %.c` and you want to build a target `testfoo`, the pattern matches `foo`, which means you have to have a file `foo.c`.

If your source file is `testfoo.c` instead, you have to write `test% : test%.c`

You can use `make -d` to understand why make is not using your pattern rule.

Comment: I am executing: ```test%: %.c
 gcc $^ -o $@``` with ```make test1``` and I get "make: *** No rule to make target 'test1'. Stop.", what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a file `1.c`?  When make matches a pattern rule `test%` with a target `test1`, the pattern `%` matches `1`.  Then when it looks at the prerequisite `%.c` it substitutes the value in the target for the `%`, giving you `1.c`.  If that file doesn't exist, then this pattern rule doesn't match and make will keep looking for some other way to build the target `test1`.  If none of the possibilities match, it says "no rule to make target".